# Minimum set of transpositions to get back to identity without reusing transpositions from a given set

Tags: algorithm, swap

We are given a set of transpositions `sigma[i] = {a, b}` which transposes `a` and `b`. How would you find a minimal set of transpositions `tau[i]` such that `sigma[i] != tau[j]` and `prod(sigma) * prod(tau) = id`, where product means composition?

Comment: The question seems to be related to sorting; however, from the current formulation, it is a bit diffucult to understand the question. Could you please provide an example? What do you mean by 'minimal' - inclusion-wise or cardinality-wise?

Comment: Please add some quantifiers to the question and provide an example.